# Many to Many relationship query returns empty queryset on post_save signal but not in django shell

Tags: django, django-models

I have a function in my model that send an email on successful save. But i am struggling to figure out why print statement on signal function in the model returns empty queryset but not in the shell. Below is my code.
**Model code**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    """Database table for users booking details"""
   //more code here
    items = models.ManyToManyField(BookingItems)
    //more code here
```

```
def send_confirmation_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Function to send email upon successfull booking creation"""
    name = instance.guest_name
    total = instance.final_total,
    email = instance.email
    order_number = instance.reservation_id
    bookingId = instance.id
    itemsData = instance.items.all()
    booking = Booking.objects.get(id=bookingId)
    bookingItems = booking.items.all()
    print(bookingItems)-----------------------------------> this returns empty queryset <QuerySet []>
    context = {"name": name, "items": itemsData, 'total': total,
               'order_number': order_number}
    message = render_to_string(
        "reservations/room_reservation_success.html", context)
    plain_message = strip_tags(message)
    subject = f"Your booking details for {instance.hotel.name}"
    mail.send_mail(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [
        email], html_message=message)


post_save.connect(send_confirmation_email, sender=Booking)
```

**Code from shell**

```
>>> book = Booking.objects.filter(id=61)
>>> print(book[0].items.all())
<QuerySet [<BookingItems: One bedroom>, <BookingItems: Two bedroom>]>
>>>
```

What could be the issue here. Why is it returning empty set when there's clearly related child items? Kindly assist

Comment: That is perfectly normal. Since if you save a many-to-many relation, you first save the object, and *then* you salve the relation with other objects. You can not do this before, since then it has no primary key yet. The `post_save` is thus triggered before populating the many-to-many field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could be the issue here. Why is it returning empty set when there's clearly related child items?

There are no related (child) items at the time the `post_save` trigger runs. Since if you save a many-to-many relation, you first save the object, and *then* you salve the relation with other objects. You can not do this before, since then it has no primary key yet. The `post_save` is thus triggered before populating the many-to-many field.

Instead of getting a trigger when the `Booking` is saved, you can for example perform a query after you add elements to the many-to-many relation with the [**`m2m_changed`** signal [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

```
def send_confirmation_email(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        # …
        pass


m2m_changed.connect(send_confirmation_email, sender=Booking.items.through)
```

That being said, signals are often [considered an *anti-pattern* [Django-doc]](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/). Especially since there are a lot of ORM calls that can circumvent signals. It might be easier to implement it in the view and thus trigger a function once the entire object is saved.

Comment: This was such an eye opener sir. Thank you..Actually i was using signals with Django rest framework serializers. I have changed my implementation by overriding ```create``` function on my serializer and and i am now able to retrieve many to many related items